# Normal approximation $P\left(\sum_{i=1}^{1500} X_{i} \leq -33 or \sum_{i=1}^{1500} X_{i} > 33\right)$

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, means, stochastic-approximation

I have a problems solving the following:

Let $X_{1},...,X_{1500}$ identical independent distributed random variable with density function: $f(t)=\frac{3}{2}t^{2} \textbf{1}_{[-1,1]}(t)$

(1) Show: $\mathbb{E}(X_{1})=0$ and $Var(X_{1})=\frac{3}{5}$

(2) Calculate $\left(\sum_{i=1}^{1500} X_{i} \leq -33 \textbf{ or }\sum_{i=1}^{1500} X_{i} > 33\right)$ with usage of normal approximation without continuity correction.

So far i could calculate **(1)** (still i am not sure if it is correct):

$E(X_{1})=\int_{-1}^{1} x_{1} \frac{3}{2} x_{1}^{2} \mathrm{d}x = \frac{3}{2}\int_{-1}^{1} x_{1}^{3} = \frac{3}{2} \left[\frac{1}{4}x^{4}\right]_{1}^{-1}=\frac{3}{2}\cdot0=0$

For the variance i used: $Var(X_{1})=E(X_{1}^{2})-E(X_{1})^{2}$ and got as result $Var(X_{1})=\frac{3}{5}$ like in the task.

What i dont understand is how to calculate the probability with the normal approximation. Usually i have tasks like e.g. $P(10 < X < 12)$ but in this case i dont understand the **or** in the text. Can you help me solving this? For now i would be happy for any hint :-)

Comment: Perhaps you mean $\text{Pr}(X\leqslant-33\text{ or }X>33)$, where $X$ is the sum if the $X_i$? If this is what you mean, have a look [here](https://people.richland.edu/james/lecture/m170/ch05-rul.html) for example.

Comment: I translated all questions exactly like it is on my sheet. The part you mentioned is 1:1 copied. This is quiet important for me since i am preparing for an exam :-)

Comment: @DavidM. but maybe it could be meant like you wrote it down. But still i dont know how to do it because of the or. This is very confusing and the only task where my teacher made use of it.

Comment: Have a look at the link I provided (first few sentences)

Comment: Interesting. I overlooked the link at the first read i think. So this means i have to calculate $P(X \leq -33)$ and $P(X>33)$ and add up the results of them. Is the idea correct?

Comment: That’s the idea, because $X\le-33$ and $X>33$ are _mutually exclusive_ (can’t happen at the same time)

Comment: Ok thank you very much. Then i will try this later this evening today and post my results here :-)